# Webpack UMD library with dynamic imports produces a ChunkLoadError when importing it in another project

Tags: webpack, code-splitting, dynamic-import, umd

I'm writing a UMD library with webpack and when I try to import it in another project (for testing), it produces a "ChunkLoadError". The error goes away when I use normal imports.

I'm trying to create a small library with code splitting.